# Match all except containing '_iq_'

Tags: regex, string, perl

**Edit:** Sorry! I should have mentioned this before. In your answers, please don't assume that the items listed below are the only things in the directory I'm searching through. These are the things I want to match with the exception of the two specified. Thanks.

This should be really easy, but everything I try just isn't doing the trick. I have the following items I need to match something to:

```
bodipr2__ds_di_uat
bodipr2__ds_dw_uat
bodipr2__ds_iq_uat
bodipr2__ds_iq_uat_back
bodipr2__ds_itsys_uat
bodipr2__ds_ppp_uat
bodipr2__ds_psd_uat
bodipr2__ds_usage_uat
bodits2__ds_pef_tst
bodits2__ds_ppp_tst
bodits2__ds_pri_tst
```

Except I want to omit the two which contain `_iq_`. So I wrote an expression like this:

```
bodi.*?__ds[^_iq_]
```

But that omits all of them. If I try this:

```
bodi.*?__ds_[^iq]
```

That omits the `_itsys_` one. I'm guessing that it's matching everything that does not contain 'i' or 'q'. I want it to omit something that does not contain `'_iq_'` at that spot.

I'm embarrassed that I even have to ask this, but if someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with this: `bod[a-z\d]+__ds_(?!iq_)\w+`
I have tested from http://regexr.com?31rho

Comment: Awesome, it does match. Let me test it really quick and I'll accept when I confirm it works in my script :)

Answer (score 3):

And just to explain **why what you tried** (`[^iq]`) **didn't work**, it's because `[^iq]` means "match any ONE character, EXCEPT if the character is "i" OR "q". And `[^_iq_]` means the same except it ALSO matches "_".

So, in your case,

- `bodi.*?__ds[^_iq_]` would have matched 100% of them because every single sring contains "_" after "ds" which will match `[^_iq_]`
- `bodi.*?__ds_[^iq]` would match only the lines that contain letters "i" or "q" after "ds", which will be - as you can now guess - **both** `_iq_` AND `_itsys_` lines.

The correct way to match "does not contain iq" is a negative look-ahead `(?!iq)` shown in Godspeed's or FailedDev's answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could skip if there *is* a match and process the rest:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    next if /^bodipr2__ds_iq_/;  # Skip if bodipr2__ds_iq_ is matched

    # Process data
    print;
}

__DATA__
bodipr2__ds_di_uat
bodipr2__ds_dw_uat
bodipr2__ds_iq_uat
bodipr2__ds_iq_uat_back
bodipr2__ds_itsys_uat
bodipr2__ds_ppp_uat
bodipr2__ds_psd_uat
bodipr2__ds_usage_uat
bodits2__ds_pef_tst
bodits2__ds_ppp_tst
bodits2__ds_pri_tst
```

Using [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @strings = qw(
  bodipr2__ds_di_uat
  bodipr2__ds_dw_uat
  bodipr2__ds_iq_uat
  bodipr2__ds_iq_uat_back
  bodipr2__ds_itsys_uat
  bodipr2__ds_ppp_uat
  bodipr2__ds_psd_uat
  bodipr2__ds_usage_uat
  bodits2__ds_pef_tst
  bodits2__ds_ppp_tst
  bodits2__ds_pri_tst
);
@strings = grep /^bodipr2__ds_iq_/ ? 0 : 1, @strings;
```

Comment: Is there no way to just filter it out in the `grep` function I'm using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not` to invert:

```
if (not /^bodi.*_iq_.*/) {
  print;
}
```

or:

```
if ($line !~ /^bodi.*_iq_.*/) {
   print;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'll fix my question to be more specific, but there are other things which are in the directory that I'm matching which don't match at all, this would cause those to be filtered through...

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;



    for (<DATA>)
    {
        chomp;
        if (! m/bodi.*_iq_/)
        {
            print $_ . "\n";
        }
    }

__DATA__
bodipr2__ds_di_uat
bodipr2__ds_dw_uat
bodipr2__ds_iq_uat
bodipr2__ds_iq_uat_back
bodipr2__ds_itsys_uat
bodipr2__ds_ppp_uat
bodipr2__ds_psd_uat
bodipr2__ds_usage_uat
bodits2__ds_pef_tst
bodits2__ds_ppp_tst
bodits2__ds_pri_tst
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code :

```
while ($subject =~ m/^(?:(?!_iq_).)*$/g) {
    print $&, "\n";
}
```

Will print everything except those two strings. You can extend this by adding more negative lookaheads after the `(?!_iq_)`.

Example test:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I saw your edit and am not sure if it could be the case that this excludes things that you want included but I tried this and it worked for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @words = qw(bodipr2__ds_di_uat
bodipr2__ds_dw_uat
bodipr2__ds_iq_uat
bodipr2__ds_iq_uat_back
bodipr2__ds_itsys_uat
bodipr2__ds_ppp_uat
bodipr2__ds_psd_uat
bodipr2__ds_usage_uat
bodits2__ds_pef_tst
bodits2__ds_ppp_tst
bodits2__ds_pri_tst);

print "Original data\n\n";

foreach my $print (@words)
{
    print "$print\n";
}

print "\nNew data\n\n";

foreach my $word (@words)
{
    next if $word =~ /bodi[a-z]+\d__[a-z]+_iq_[a-z]+/;
    print "$word\n";
}
```